# question about C pointer on boolean value,

Tags: c, boolean, unary-function

```
int bar(int *arr, size_t n)
{
    int sum = 0, i;
    for (i = n; i > 0; i--)
    {
        sum += !arr[i - 1];
    }
    return ~sum + 1;
}
```

I have come across this code but don't quite understand `sum += !arr[i - 1];`:  what is the effect of !(NOT) applied to the pointer of an array? Also, what is the effect of ~ before `sum`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sum += !arr[i - 1];
```

The `!` is the **Logical Negation** operator. It is not applied on a pointer as you mention, but on the value `arr[i-1]`. If `arr[i-1] ==0` the result is `1` otherwise the result is 0.

```
~sum + 1;
```

`~` is the **Bitwise NOT operator** It will invert all the binary bits of `sum`. It is sometimes also called the **ones complement**

The result of `~sum +1` is the same as taking the two's complement of `sum`, which is equal to the negative of sum. If sum is `5` it will return `-5`

**Some more explanation on the Logical Operators**

When the Logical operators (Logical AND, OR, NOT) are applied on a variable, it only checks the *logical* state of the variable. i.e. this is whether this is `0` or `non 0` Non zero can take any value e.g. `5, 10, -5` etc.

So, if you apply `!0`  you get the value of 1. For any other value e.g. `!5` the answer is 0.

From C99 6.5.3.5

> The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is equivalent to (0==E)

Comment: in this line !arr[i - 1], so the ! operator will turn the result to 1 if arr[i-1] ==0? could you please elaborate a bit more?